# projection is not preserved in nginx+ffmpeg 360 video streaming

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp, 360-video

I am using nginx rtmp module and ffmpeg to stream a 360 degree video, I Am able to stream and play in VLC player, however in during playback 360 video is not preserved. video is playing side by side. Following is my command

```
sudo ffmpeg  -i sampleVideo.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -vprofile high  -acodec aac -f flv rtmp://localhost/show/stream2
```

Comment: Having the same issue with a live stream to a RTMP server from a Insta360 One R